# A Semaphore example

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

Let we have two semaphores S and Q and both initialized to 1 :

```
P0      P1
Wait(S) Wait(S)
Wait(Q) Wait(Q)
…   …
…   …
Signal(S)   Signal(Q)
Signal(S)   Signal(S)
```

What is the unwanted situatuin(s) that will happen here ? Also what is the effect of the second signal call on s made by process p0 on this situation (s) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of this depends on the implementation of the semaphore. Is it a counting semaphore or binary? If counting, does it have a maximum or is it unlimited?

A bad situation that can occur is if `P0` executes first, `Q` is acquired but never released, so `P1` will wait on `Q` forever.

Another bad situation that can occur is if `P0` executes first, and `P1` executes between the two `Signal(S)` calls in `P0` (ignoring the `Wait(Q)` bit for now). `P1` is released, and assumes it has exclusive access on `S`, but then `P0` executes the second `Signal(S)`, breaking the assumption of mutual exclusivity.

The effect of the second `Signal(S)` depends on the semaphore. If it's binary, then it will be re-signaled if it was acquired between the first and second `Signal(S)` calls. If nothing was acquired, it will do nothing.

If it's a counting semaphore, then its counter will be incremented, or any additional waiting threads will be allowed to proceed. If it has a maximum value, then this value won't be exceeded.